# Properness for uncountable models

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

There are certain generalizations of the notion of a proper forcing to uncountable cardinals in the context of forcing iterations. For example, the ones introduced by Eisworth, and by Roslanowski and Shelah. They usually considered such a notion under some cardinal arithmetic assumptions and in the context of iterated forcings.

I am simply looking for a reference for the following definition:

- **Definition**: Suppose $\mathcal S$ is a set of uncountable elementary submodels in some large $H_\theta$, and $\mathbb P$ is a forcing notion belonging to every model in  $\mathcal S$.
  As in the definition of a proper forcing, let us say that $\mathbb P$ is $\mathcal S$-proper if, for every $M\in\mathcal S$ and every $p\in\mathbb P\cap M$, there is an $(M,\mathbb P)$-generic condition $q\leq p$.

I considered the above definition and the following theorem as folklore, but I was asked by a referee to provide a reference for them.

- **Theorem**:  Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, and $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal P_\kappa(H_\theta)$ is stationary. If $\mathbb P$ is $\mathcal S$-proper, then $\mathbb P$ preserves $\kappa$.

I think calling it $\kappa$-properness can be confusing for several reasons, including the fact that the set $\mathcal S$ is just stationary.

**Question 1**: Does the above notion have a name in the literature? If not, is my terminology convenient? What about "*$\mathbb P$ is proper for $\mathcal S$*"?

**Question 2:** What is the most appropriate work to cite for the above theorem?

Comment: You have to assume $M \cap \kappa \in \kappa$ for every $M\in\mathcal S$, right?

Answer (score 4):

The concept first appeared in Shelah's paper  [Independence results](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/100/)

The theorem you have stated should be folklore, but you may see Tapani Hyttinen and Mika Rautila, [The canary tree revisited](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/canary-tree-revisited/90AFA67942E37F70A6B4DAECDDFEDB06)
for a proof.

Of course in the above cited papers, the definitions are not given for some stationary set, but that is clear how to modify them for this case.

Finally, a very good reference to look at is the following paper by Roslanowski: [Shelah's search for properness for iterations with uncountable supports](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=FF16AD9F147C55F4C1CBECBDB239CC53?doi=10.1.1.104.5614&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: I know how to prove the theorem. Probably I have to state it as folklore and provide a proof.